# How to render different types of objects in the same list with grails json views?

Tags: grails, gson, json-view

I have a structure of classes as:

```
class A {
...
}

class B extends A {
...
}

class C extends A {
...
}
```

No, in the controller I am fetching a list of objects of mixed types:

```
A[] objects = bethodTpFetchTheList()
```

In the view, I need to render the whole list, but I need to use a different template for different types.

Is it even possible?

When I had a single type, I used to render the json this way:

```
json tmpl.object(objects)
```

Is there is a way to manually iterate through the list and make the decision base on the type?

**SOME PROGRESS**
So I got to this:

```
json utilizations, { ToolUtilization utilization ->
    if (utilization.type == ToolType.TOOL_40_PRINCIPLES) {
        tmpl.'/fortyPrinciplesUtilization/utilization'(utilization)
    } else if (utilization.type == ToolType.RRM){
        tmpl.'/rrmUtilization/utilization'(utilization)
    }
}
```

It kinda works, but it renders empty objects...

**SOME MORE PROGRESS**

It seems like if I use `g.inline` it partially works, but it does not pick up the template. So, if I do this:

```
json(utilizations) { ToolUtilization utilization ->
    if (utilization.type == ToolType.TOOL_40_PRINCIPLES) {
        g.inline(utilization) <= here it renders the object with a default renderer.
    } else if (utilization.type == ToolType.RRM){
        g.inline(template:'/rrmUtilization/utilization', model:[utilization: utilization])
    }
}
```

The other one with template defined, produces an empty object.

Comment: Does "empty object" mean JSON that looks like `{}`, or something else?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Exactly

Answer (score -1):

It really depends on the particulars but this might help.

The ideal thing would be to organize the data into separate lists back in the controller or service layer and keep your view layer more simple but to answer the question as asked, the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/renderjsonobjects shows one way to do it.

Files of interest:

https://github.com/jeffbrown/renderjsonobjects/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/renderjsonobjects/DemoController.groovy

```
package renderjsonobjects

class DemoController {
    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']

    def index() {
        // the intent here is just to simulate a list of
        // instances of different types...
        def results = []
        results << new Person(name: 'Zack')
        results << new Address(town: 'St. Louis')
        results << new Person(name: 'Matt')
        results << new Address(town: 'San Jose')

        respond view: 'index', model: [theData: results]
    }
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/renderjsonobjects/blob/master/grails-app/views/demo/_person.gson is a template for rendering a `Person`.

```
import renderjsonobjects.Person

model {
    Person person
}

json {
    name person.name
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/renderjsonobjects/blob/master/grails-app/views/demo/_address.gson is a template for rendering an `Address`:

```
import renderjsonobjects.Address

model {
    Address address
}

json {
    town address.town
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/renderjsonobjects/blob/master/grails-app/views/demo/index.gson iterates over the heterogenous `List` and renders a different template for the different types.  Again, this is probably not really the best solution to whatever your real problem is, but this is a way to get there.

```
import renderjsonobjects.Address
import renderjsonobjects.Person

json {
    Map theModel = (Map)binding.variables.model
    List data = (List)theModel.theData
    people tmpl.person(data.findAll { it instanceof Person })
    addresses tmpl.address(data.findAll { it instanceof Address})
}
```

That will render something like this:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/demo
{"people":[{"name":"Zack"},{"name":"Matt"}],"addresses":[{"town":"St. Louis"},{"town":"San Jose"}]}
```

**UPDATE BASED ON COMMENT:**

See https://github.com/jeffbrown/renderjsonobjects/commit/13aea5db090cd38a2039e08fb9b675630d5bf565.

That makes https://github.com/jeffbrown/renderjsonobjects/blob/master/grails-app/views/demo/index.gson look like the following:

```
json (((Map)binding.variables.model).theData)
```

That results in the following being rendered:

```
[[{"name":"Zack"},{"town":"St. Louis"},{"name":"Matt"},{"town":"San Jose"}]]
```

I think that satisfies the question as asked.  If you want to see the JSON structured differently, if you can provide desired output, that would help.

Comment: That was not the target. I specifically need them in a single list.

Comment: Apologies.  When you said "render different types of objects in the same list" I misunderstood and thought "in the same list" was referencing where the objects were that needed to be rendered, as opposed to where they needed to be rendered.

Comment: @ShurikAgulyansky Does the update I added above satisfy your requirement ot have all of the objects rendered in the same JSON list?